# odoo is not recognizing python modules

Tags: python, windows, odoo, odoo-8

i have installed beautifulsoup4 using pip install BeautifulSoup and through normal python project it can import the module. (from bs4 import BeautifulSoup) but in odoo it get error no module name bs4 even though it is installed. does anyone have solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure odoo is using the Python installation you think it is (I'd guess it's not).

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Try that from a python prompt where `import bs4` works and from the odoo prompt where it doesn't.  The difference should give you the answer.

Comment: #cco You are right odoo is not using python installation. I am using windows and the output of sys.path was the odoo installation directory server folder. is there any parm in openerp-server.conf to set the python location.

Comment: I dont' use odoo, so I'm not sure what you're supposed to do.  Checking pypi, it looks like bs4 doesn't have any binary components, so you should be able to copy the bs4 from you installed python to the odoo site-packages directory (as long as they are both Py2 or both Py3).